# Output string list variable from python script to another python scrip in Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've tried several articles and threads on Stackoverflow but cannot seem to find a solution the problem I'm having. This might be a simple answer but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have two steps in my YAML pipeline script. Both call python scripts.

In the first Python script I can making an API call to ultimately retrieve a list of strings. I am storing these as a Pipeline variable:

```
repo_languages = ['csharp', 'java']
print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=REPO_LANGAUGES;]{repo_languages}')
```

I want to then retrieve this variable in a separate python script in a later build step.

I can get this to work for a string but not a list of strings with:

```
repo_languages = os.environ.get('REPO_LANGAUGES')
```

I feel like this is probably a trivial answer, but I just can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables - which Azure pipeline variables turn into - can only be strings, not lists. If you want to pass a list of values between steps then you'll have to turn that list into a string on the setting end and parse that string on the receiving end.

For example, the setter can set a single variable to a string consisting of the values joined together by commas, which the receiver can then `split()` back into a list, as in the code below.

Earlier step:

```
print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=REPO_LANGUAGES;]{",".join(repo_languages)}')
```

Later step:

```
repo_languages = os.environ.get('REPO_LANGUAGES').split(',')
```

Comment: Fair enough. That makes sense. I will do it this way instead.